# Como arrumar o erro num_rows property

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mariadb

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida referente á este erro:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\controle\inc\database.php on line 94.

Segue parte do código.

```
function find( $table = null, $id_tag = null ) {            
    $database = open_database();        
    $found = null;          

    try {         
        if ($id_tag) {         
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE id= " . $id_tag;            
             $result = $database->query($sql);                      

             if ($result->num_rows > 0) {             
                 $found = $result->fetch_assoc();           
                }                     
            } else {                       
                 $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;          
                $result = $database->query($sql);                       
             **if ($result->num_rows > 0) {           
                $found = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);**                            
                }        
             }      

         } catch (Exception $e) {         
            $_SESSION['message'] = $e->GetMessage();          
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';     }             
            close_database($database);      
            return $found;  
}
```

Comment: esse erro significa que `$result` não contem a propriedade `num_rows` ou seja, a query esta a retornar algum erro tenta [seguir este exemplo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) tem em atenção fechar a result set após a query

Comment: Basicamente a query falhou porque a tabela ou o campo não existe. Tanto quanto vejo nos parametros até podem ser `null` o que faz com que o SQL potencialmente possa ser `select * from null where id = null`. Faça `var_dump($sql)` antes da execução da `query` para ver exatamente o comando que está a correr e perceber o problema.